# CSS / Jquery - Responsive Hover

Tags: jquery, css, responsive-design

I would like to implement a hover effect to a responsive blog list -

Basically I'm using a styled version of this - http://startbootstrap.com/3-col-portfolio and i"d like to fade in a grey overlay with 'readmore' button whenever hovering over a particlualt blog as in ythis quickly mocked image -

[image]

I figured I could place divs on top of one another within the blog div and fade in/out on hover as in this -

```
<div class="col-md-4 portfolio-item">
        <div style="background:#FFF;" class="top">
            <a href="#project-link">
                <img class="img-responsive" src="http://breadwinningmama.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/04/fitness-running-shoes_fe.jpg">
            </a>
            <h3><a href="#project-link">A Fitness Article</a>
            </h3>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam viverra euismod odio, gravida pellentesque urna.. <a href="articleInfo.html">Read More</a></p>
        </div>
        <div style="background:#000; width:100px; height:100px;" class="cover">
        read more
        </div>

        <div>

        </div>
        </div>


$(document).ready(function() {

$('.portfolio-item ').mouseenter(function() {
  $('.top').fadeOut('slow', function() {
    // Animation complete.
  });

  $('.cover').fadeIn('slow', function() {
    // Animation complete.
  });
}).mouseleave(function() {
  $('.top').fadeIn('slow', function() {
    // Animation complete.
  });

  $('.cover').fadeOut('slow', function() {
    // Animation complete.
  });
 });
 });
</script>
```

but as its responsive I'm not sure how I would get each div to fill the required space - or whether thats the best way to achieve what i want.  any advice?

Comment: You haven't opened the script element: `<script type="text/javascript">`

Comment: Can you make a fiddle?

Comment: I've tried to make a fiddle with the given code but it causes an almost infinite loop of fades when you hover over the supplied image...

Comment: hi chris thats not the full code - just a snipped to explain what i was talking about - i'll make a fiddle

Comment: You could do the whole thing with CSS and a `:hover` though.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/brainbolt/52VtD/4/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using your code, I think you could try something like this...

HTML

```
<div class="col-md-4 portfolio-item">
    <div class="top">
        <a href="#project-link">
            <img class="img-responsive" src="http://breadwinningmama.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/04/fitness-running-shoes_fe.jpg">
        </a>
     <h3><a href="#project-link">A Fitness Article</a></h3>
     <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam viverra euismod odio, gravida pellentesque urna...</p>
</div>
<div class="cover"><a href="articleInfo.html">Read More</a></div>
```

CSS

```
.portfolio-item{
    position:relative;
}

.cover{
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background:#444;
    opacity: .4;    
}

.portfolio-item:hover .cover{
    display:block;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for the effect that the images have, then you are probably looking for this: 
[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HAcE2/772/)

I ignored your code and made it with a different way!There's no need to use `JQuery` when you can achieve it with `css`

***Html:***

```
<a href="#" class="wrapper">
    <span class="text">
        Read More!
    </span>
    <img src="http://www.1stwebdesigner.com/wp-content/uploads/2009/11/webdesign-books-wishlist/css-missing-manual-books-web-development-books.jpg">
</a>
```

***CSS:***

```
.wrapper {
    position: relative;
    padding: 0;
    width:100px;
    display:block;
}
.text {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    color:#f00;
    background-color:rgba(255,255,255,0.7);
    width: 300px;
    height: 391px;
    line-height:100px;
    text-align: center;
    z-index: 10;
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
}
.text:hover {
    opacity:1;
}

img {
    z-index:1;
}
span.text
{
  width: 300px;
  height: 391px;
  color: #000;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 391px; /* Magic Trick to align text " vertically " */
}
```

Let me know if this worked for you! :)